# Rearrange Pandas Dataframe, split rows and transpose

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot, transpose

I'd like to convert a Datafram which has this format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04'],
           "A1": [1, 2, 2, 2],
           "A2": [9, 2, 2, 3],
           "A3": [1, 3, 2, 9],
           "B1": [1, 8, 2, 3],
           "B2": [3, 8, 9, 3],
           "B3": [2, 4, 5, 5]})
```

| Date | A1 | A2 | A3 | B1 | B2 | B3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 | 9 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 2021-01-02 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 8 | 8 | 4 |
| 2021-01-03 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 9 | 5 |
| 2021-01-04 | 2 | 3 | 9 | 3 | 3 | 5 |

What I want to create table, that just starts with letters in the rows.
My idea is the following:

1. Add 2 dummy rows after every row with date
2. Copy the values from (X2) und (X3) into that dummy row for the same date
3. Delete the Columns (X2) and (X3)
4. transpose the whole table

The target format looks like this:

| Date | 2021-01-01 (1) | 2021-01-01 (2) | 2021-01-02 (3) | 2021-01-02 (4) | 2021-01-02 (5) | 2021-01-02 (6) | 2021-01-03 1 (7) | 2021-01-03 (8) | 2021-01-03 (9) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 9 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 8 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| B | 1 | 3 | 2 | 8 | 8 | 4 | 2 | 9 | 5 |

I couldnt get it to work, I'll try to post the code later on.

Is there any cleaner, faster way to do so?
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `melt` to get the long format to construct the corresponding date format for each category:

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='Date') # in each row: 2021-01-01 | A1 | 1
df['idx'] = df['variable'].str[:-1] # A, B, ...
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str) + ' (' +  df['variable'].str[-1] + ')'
df = df[['Date', 'idx', 'value']].pivot(values='value', index='idx', columns='Date')
```

set `df.index.name = None` if you don't want the col shown:

```
Date    2021-01-01 (1)  2021-01-01 (2)  2021-01-01 (3)  2021-01-02 (1)  2021-01-02 (2)  2021-01-02 (3)  2021-01-03 (1)  2021-01-03 (2)  2021-01-03 (3)  2021-01-04 (1)  2021-01-04 (2)  2021-01-04 (3)
A   1   9   1   2   2   3   2   2   2   2   3   9
B   1   3   2   8   8   4   2   9   5   3   3   5
```

Comment: Clean, simple, does the Job.
Thank you very much.